# Facebook 'Like' keeps resetting to 0

Tags: facebook, button, facebook-like

```
<iframe src="//www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=http%3A%2F%2Fchinaphonearena.com&amp;send=false&amp;layout=button_count&amp;width=100&amp;show_faces=false&amp;font=arial&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;action=like&amp;height=21&amp;appId=117777795070982" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:100px; height:21px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
```

I've tried it with HTML, IFRAME, HTML5 pasted direct code from the facebook like button generator...with the same result.

It's still resetting to zero.

You can see there's no errors in the debugger.

http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fchinaphonearena.com

This is tied into a facebook page which has the website URL set to the URL within the code.

What's interesting is if I run my website through the debug tool, it INSTANTLY gets a count back. If it's reading '0', then go run the URL through facebook debugger it sets it back to '4'. Some hours later it will return to '0'. If running the URL through the debugger, instantly back to '4' again.

This is driving me crazy. Anyone knows the solution, thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. (I think). The link within the code was leading to mysite.com, but the .htaccess redirect leads to mysite.com/forum. By changing the link in the facebook button code to mysite.com/forum, the counter now stays.